# Loading gif and progress bar on start up

Tags: startup, power-management, nvram

After doing a pram and a smc reset my late 2011 mac book pro 10.8 shows the apple logo on a grey screen with a loading gif and a progress bar which once finished the mac just turns off.

I have got the error in the disk utility of my hard drive. "Invalid index key"

I am currently backing up the hard drive in the disk utility!

Comment: Did you do the SMC reset while the MB was in Safe Sleep, Hibernation, Suspend-To-Disk?

Comment: No I tried 2 techniques but when I did the take the charger out for 15 secs that seems to be when it broke.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your hard disk is failing. Backup all your date with Time Machine. Then boot in to Recovery Parition by starting up and holdind the keys cmd-R. Try to repair the disk with Disk Utility. Anyway, consider to replace it.